# Turning off multiple game objects at once in Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm wanting to turn off multiple game objects and all their associated children at once with a single method call.

My thinking behind this was to create a list to hold all of the game objects I want to deactivate and pass all those objects in. However, I'm trying to implement the actual `SetActive` method call with my list and Im running into some issues.

Here is my code just now:

```
public List<GameObject> deactivate_Screen = new List<GameObject>(); 

void OnClick()
{       
    for( int i = 0; i < deactivate_Screen.Count; i++)
    {
        deactivate_Screen.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Now the obvious reason this isn't working is clear to me. A list can't access to the SetActive function I'm trying to achieve. However, I'm at a loss to implement the functionality I require.

Could someone please show me what I need to do, or point me in the right direction to fix my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly recognized, [`SetActive`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) is a method of a `GameObject`, not of the [`List<GameObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You have to invoke `SetActive` in each iteration for the game object the index `i` of the current iteration refers to - you can access that object with the [`List<T>` indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. by placing square brackets with the index behind `deactivate_Screen`.

Thus, the "current item" in each iteration is `deactivate_Screen[i]`, hence your loop should look as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < deactivate_Screen.Count; i++)
{
    deactivate_Screen[i].SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

`deactivate_Screen.SetActive(false);`

to

`deactivate_Screen[i].SetActive(false);`

As `List` itself is not a game object but its elements are `List[0] List[1] List[2] List[3].....`

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you need to access the element of the list at the index *i*:

```
for( int i = 0; i < deactivate_Screen.Count; i++)
{
    deactivate_Screen[i].SetActive(false);
}
```

or using a foreach loop

```
foreach (var gobj in deactivate_Screen)
{
    gobj.SetActive(false);
}
```